# Where to initialize custom UIView, instantiated in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a subclass of UIView that's instantiated in a XIB file. I need it to do some initialization (settings some variables and creating a subview).

However, I do not always instantiate this view via Interface Builder. I do it programmatically too. In both cases, the initialization needs to be the same.

My designated initializer is `initWithValues:`.

The question is; **where do I perform the initialization?**

Since I have to perform it in 2 different locations, I figured I need to refactor it in a separate `initialize` method (or something like that), and call it from `initWithValues:`.

But when loading from IB, both `initWithCoder:` and `awakeFromNib` are called. From which method do I have to call `initialize`? Or do I have to call `initWithValues:` from `initWithCoder:` and do nothing in `awakeFromNib`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `initWithFrame:` when initializing views (since it's the designated initializer).  Hence, if you have `initWithValues:` make sure you call `initWithFrame:` from it.

Something like this should work for initializing: ;)

```
- (void)initialize{
     //init your ivars here
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder]){
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:rect]){
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I was going to add a further explanation, but mplappert's answer is clear enough. Use `awakeFromNib` if necessary.

Comment: Isn't it 'wrong' to call two different initializers of the superclass? Shouldn't I call the designated initializer of my subclass (`initWithValues:`) from `initWithCoder:`?

Comment: Isn't it 'wrong' to call two different initializers of the superclass? →No because only one of them will be called. Shouldn't I call the designated initializer of my subclass (initWithValues:) from initWithCoder:? →partially yes. initWithCoder: expects you to unarchive the object. That is why we call [super initWithCoder]; by doing this the view will be initialized. Now you only need to init other ivars, something I assume you are doing inside of initialize method.

Answer (score 10):

That depends on what you need to initialize. As soon as `awakeFromNib` gets called, all outlets and action connections of your view are established which is not the case in `initWithCoder:`. So if you need to rely on those connections, use awakeFromNib. Otherwise you can safely do all your initializing in `initWithCoder:`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the above answers don't take into account these things:
- (void) awakeAfterUsingCoder - and the fact it's called after anything is created by the coder (once for every Xib view).
awakeFromNib suffers from the same fate, I've noticed. (The reason I found this)

Another initializing issue is that initWithCoder and initWithFrame can be avoided for custom views. And if they are called, lazy loading (though not as important on views themselves), means you "might" be able to modify values. I believe I've done so in initWithCoder, but if you then initialize values in awakeFromNib, it's undone at least once.

I've gone so far as to:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib (or didMoveToSuperView);
{
    BOOL called = NO;
    if(!called)
    {
    called = YES;
    }

}
```

Another method I use is to simply call the initializer needed, then call my own class or superclass-specific initializer.

I, too, am looking for a dependable one-time place I can rely on. Until then, I hope my headaches save the next person an hour or so.

Steve

Comment: I think that `didMoveToSuperView` is a pretty good place to do it for most views - it'll cover manual and NIB instantiation without multiple init methods. Not so good if you need the view to perform any logic before it's on-screen, but if you're doing that then there's probably something wrong...

Comment: Yeah, it's actually what I resorted to eventually, but even it has a flaw. When it's removed and its superview is nil, it's also called. Not good for rearranging, so I added a test for "if superview nil" much like the called test. Watch out for that! Thanks for the answer :D