# Custom UIView in IB

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder

I have created a custom subclass of UIView for an interface element that I want to create on an iPad screen. (it creates a list of buttons)

To use this view, I have added a view in IB, set the size properly, and updated the class to be of my sub-class.

When I run my project, non of the buttons are created, because the - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame is never called.

So to the question.  When elements are created by virtue of being in IB, what delegate should I implement that will properly init my class?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `initWithCoder:` and call some common code that `initWithFrame:` also calls.  The first will be called to initialize from a nib, the second to initialize from code.

`awakeFromNib` is also an option, that would happen later in the life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty well documented in the [UIView reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) under methods to override.

- Override `initWithCoder:` to handle your view being instantiated from a NIB
- Override `initWithFrame:` to support creating your view from code

More information is available in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579342/where-to-initialize-custom-uiview-instantiated-in-interface-builder). That looks pretty much identical to your question actually...