# How do I set a nonzero initial value in iOS?

Tags: ios, button, synthesize

I have an ivar which is mentioned in my header

```
@interface MyClass : UIView{
    int thistone;}
- (IBAction)toneButton:(UIButton *)sender;
@property int thistone;
@end
```

and I have synthesized it in the implementation:

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize thistone;
- (IBAction)toneButton:(UIButton *)sender {
if(thistone<4)
    {thistone=1000;}   // I hate this line.
    else{thistone=thistone+1; }  
}
```

I cannot find (or find in any manual) a way to set a nonzero initial value. I want it to start at 1000 and increase by 1 each time I press the button.   The code does exactly what I intend, but I'm guessing there's a more proper way to do it that saves me the if/else statement above.  Code fixes or pointers to specific lines in online documentation greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use the init* methods. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579342/where-to-initialize-custom-uiview-instantiated-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object has a variant of the `init` method called at instantiation. Implement this method to do such setup. UIView in particular have `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder`. Best to override all and call a separate method to perform required setup.

For example:

```
- (void)commonSetup
{
    thisTone = 1000;
}


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self commonSetup];
    }

    return self;
}


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder])
    {
        [self commonSetup];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Wow. How'd you know I was still playing with CGRect? It works, and I guess I have a lot more reading to do.  thanks.   Actually, a lot more code typing than my if/else, but takes me deeper into Obj C concepts. thanks.